# PICO-8 Export Command in a GitHub CI/CD Pipeline

Tags: javascript, azure-static-website-hosting, pico-8

I'm working a small PICO-8 game that I am embedding into my website. There's an [export](https://pico-8.fandom.com/wiki/Export) command I use to create the game files for the web player, but I can only run this command locally in the PICO-8 application.

Is there any support to run this [export](https://pico-8.fandom.com/wiki/Export) command in a terminal session on some Linux distro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the export command explained here: https://pico-8.fandom.com/wiki/Export. One format is html which can be embedded into a webpage.

Also found this information for exporting from the command line (they read as `headless`): https://pico-8.fandom.com/wiki/RunningPico8

```
pico8 [flags] [filename.p8]
-export param_str : run EXPORT command in headless mode and exit (see Export)
```

Comment: Thanks Brett. I would like to know if it's possible to run this export command in a remote host, like as part of a step in GitHub actions in a CI/CD pipeline. I modified the question title to reflect this.

Comment: I really don't think so as from what I understand there are no command line options for the pico-8 executable file. The export command is run from within the application. It may be worth making a feature request to Zep (creator at Lexaloffle) for command line options. I like the idea :)

Comment: Never mind my last comment, it's already available. See my updated answer @greg

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea the `pico.exe` accepted command line flags. Now I need to figure out how to host thes `pico.exe` in GitHub so I can call if from my CI/CD action. Since Pico8 is paid software that may now be allowed. I'll do some more research on it that other topic.

Comment: I have the feeling (!) that the pico8 executable ultimately uses [emscripten](https://emscripten.org/docs/introducing_emscripten/about_emscripten.html?highlight=lua) / [lua.vm.js](https://daurnimator.github.io/lua.vm.js/lua.vm.js.html) to generate the HTML/JS package. Would be interesting to find out.